# Combinations of resistor networks?

Tags: combinatorics

I formulated this question while thinking about resistor networks.

Suppose you are given N distinct resistors.  How many ways are there to combine them into a resistor network?

A resistor network is one of the following:

- a single resistor
- two resistor networks connected in parallel
- two resister networks connected in series

The two later cases are commutative and associative. ie A+B = B+A and (X+Y)+Z = X+(Y+Z).  Equal networks should only be counted once.

By what method can we calculate the number of combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this other question is about identical resistors but it is nearly duplicate

[Given $n$ identical resistors $R$, find combinations of series, parallel, and series-parallel arrangements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14645)