# How many 2-terminal graphs with fixed number of edges?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For a fixed positive integer n, I would like to enumerate all electric circuits with n labelled resistors. I am thinking of an electric circuit as a 2-terminal graph and a resistor as an edge of the graph. How many 2-terminal graphs are there with a fixed number of n edges?

The graphs could be either planar or non-planar, connected or not and should not be restricted to series-parallel graphs.

Here there is the number of series-parallel graphs:
https://oeis.org/A006351

Another related question is:
[Given $n$ identical resistors $R$, find combinations of series, parallel, and series-parallel arrangements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14645/given-n-identical-resistors-r-find-combinations-of-series-parallel-and-se?rq=1)

Comment: How far have you gone in enumerating these graphs? What is the integer sequence you have so far? Perhaps a list of the first few examples of these graphs would be helpful.